# How to retrieve BDD & FTP informations in ISPConfig

Tags: web-hosting

I manage my websites with ISPConfig 3.0.4. This is a great tool but I have problems with the FTP and database manager :

I create a lot of site every day, and it's very annoying to type username and password every time, save and share them to my partners.

How to make FTP & BDD passwords automatically generated ?
There is a way to email me these ?

Probably by scripting database_edit.php and ftp_user_edit.php files ?

In short, I am looking for a way to facilitate these tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make you own script to create FTP & BDD users and then sending an email directly.

ISPConfig 3 delivers a remote API using SOAP Protocol.

Check out the API documentation which is in PHP : [Ispconfig-API-Doc](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-create-remote-api-scripts-for-ispconfig-3)

You just have to create a remote user in the ISPconfig Panel and then connect to your server with the API. Then use functions delivered by the API for each registration you want to do.

I created a wrapper in Python using the remote API : [Ispconfig remote API Wrapper](https://github.com/rodneyrd/py-ispconfig)